# how to pass the class_id with section_id both in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have 3 dependable dropdown boxes and first i select the class and it will select all the sections belong to that class. and when i select the respective section i want to get the students in that section...

```
<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('class'); ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select name="class_id" class="form-control selectboxit" id="classid" onchange="return get_student_section(this.value)">
        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class'); ?></option>
          <?php
        $classes = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
          foreach ($classes as $row):
          print_r($classes);
          ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>

      </select> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('section');?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
      <select name="section_id" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" 
        id="student_selector_holder" onchange="get_class_section_students(this.value)">
        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class_first'); ?></option>
          </select> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('student'); ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
      <select name="student_id" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" id="student_selection_holder">
        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class_first'); ?></option>
      </select> </div>
</div>
```

my ajax request looks alike this. what i want to do is when i select the section i want to trigger an ajax call with class_id and _section_id. this is my javascript code

```
function get_student_section(class_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/get_student_section/' + class_id,
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery('#student_selector_holder').html(response);
        }
    });
}

function get_class_section_students(section_id) {
    //Get
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    alert("bla" + bla);
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/get_class_students_by_section/' + class_id + section_id,
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery('#student_selection_holder').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use jquery - i would attach any event handler to the selected element via jQuerys "on" function instead of using "onchange" directly

i try to give you an approach which should work

the js Code

```
var app = window.app || {};

app.autoLoad = function()
{
    app.dropdownBuilder.initialize();
};

app.dropdownBuilder = 
{
    initialize : function()
    {
        var that = this;

        $("#classid").on("change", function()   {
            that.loadStudentSection($(this).val());
        });

        $("#student_selector_holder").on("change", function()   {
            that.loadClassSectionStudents($("#classid").val(), $(this).val());
        });
    },

    loadStudentSection : function(class_id) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: app.constants.baseUrl+'index.php?admin/get_student_section/' + class_id +'/',
            success: function(response) 
            {
                $('#student_selector_holder').html(response);
            }
        });
    },

    loadClassSectionStudents : function(class_id, section_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: app.constants.baseUrl+'index.php?admin/get_class_students_by_section/' + class_id +'/'+ section_id+'/',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#student_selection_holder').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
};

app.constants = 
{
    baseUrl : "<?=base_url(); ?>"
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    app.autoLoad();
});
```

the view looked okay - i removed the onchange events

```
<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('class'); ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select name="class_id" class="form-control selectboxit" id="classid">
        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class'); ?></option>
        <?php
            $classes = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
            foreach ($classes as $row):
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('section');?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select name="section_id" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" id="student_selector_holder">
            <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class_first'); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('student'); ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
        <select name="student_id" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" id="student_selection_holder">
            <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_class_first'); ?></option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass only `this` in `onchange` function like `onchange="get_class_section_students(this)"`

and in JavaScript use `section_id.value`

Comment: i am already able to get this section id, but i want to pass the class id and section id both in the second ajax request? how to do this?

Comment: @sud then you have to pass it like: `onchange="get_class_section_students(this, document.getElementById('classid').value)"`  which is not a good approach